# Routing USB3 signals

Tags: pcb, usb, pcb-design

I'm designing a USB3 PCB. USB3 tracks should have 90Ohm differential impedance.

The board is FR4 with 35um copper on the top layer. How can I calculate the track width / distance / distance to others?

I want to use tracks of 0.1mm or 0.2mm.

Comment: With the dielectric constant an one of the many online differential trace width calculators?

Comment: https://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/edge-coupled-microstrip-impedance. If your board thickness from top layer to earth plane is 1.6mm you'll have problems.

Comment: Yes I planed to use a 2 layer PCB, as the circuit is realy simple (One chip only). But maybe this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

For anything that fast I would be starting with a 4 layer stackup with buried ground plane and give some thought to the stackup.

You can do 45 ohm lines (90 ohm differential) on 1.6mm DS FR4 but they are **HUGE** and not suitable for this. Your other option if 2 layer is important might be to go to a very much thinner board, 0.8mm is standard and thinner is available, but 4 layer does not have much of a premium over two and makes for much better SI.

CPW may be a possibility but that has issues of its own if you cannot stitch heavily.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Find out electric field relative permeability of the FR4 at your manufacturer.

Step 2) Use a calculator to find the [impedance of a differential microstrip](http://www.multek.se/engelska/engineering/pcb-structures-2/differential-microstrip-impedance-calculator-2) transmission line.

I'll include the equations below:

[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmwaL.gif)

$$ Z_d = \frac{174}{\sqrt{\epsilon_r+1.41}}\left(\ln{\frac{5.98*h}{0.8*w+t}}\right)\left(1-0.48\exp{\left(-0.96\frac{d}{h}\right)}\right) $$